# What is constructor in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I don't understand the difference between test_1 and test_2.

（If I create a function that calls testMessage, both will work the same.）

```
contract test_1 {
 string testMessage = "Hello,world!";
}

contract test_2 {
 string testMessage;
   constructor() {
     testMessage = "Hello,world!";
   }
}
```

As mentioned earlier, when I call testMessage, Hello world is displayed properly in both cases.
like this.

```
function getMessage() public view returns(string){
 return testMessage;
}
```

result
--> Hello,world!

I know that constructors have a special meaning, but I don't know what their role is.

Comment: Constructor is useful if you want to initialize state variable based on the sender of the contract. For example, you want to set the owner of contract in a state variable. But, you could just write it in contract file because the sender could be anyone.

Answer (score 2):

Constructor in solidity used to initialize the state variables of smart contracts. When you use the constructor, the testMessage will be initialized with **"Hello, world!"** in your case.

Comment: Thank you to answer.
Isn't it necessary to use the constructor if the output results are the same?

Answer (score 2):

Constructors are special function that runs only 1 time in the entire lifetime of the contract you are deploying. In the first case, you declared a variable as string , which will return the message . In the second case, you mentioned it in the constructor , when the contract is deployed , the variable will have this message as well.

Therefore both return same.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is an optional function that is executed upon contract creation , declared using constructor keyword. Constructor is used to initialize state variables of a contract.

Following are the key characteristics of a constructor.

- A contract can have only one constructor.
- A constructor code is executed once when a contract is created and it is used to initialize contract state.
- After a constructor code executed, the final code is deployed to blockchain.
- Constructor code or any internal method used only by constructor are not included in final code.

A constructor can be either public or internal.

A internal constructor marks the contract as abstract.

In case, no constructor is defined, a default constructor is present in the contract.

Here is some example code & video that explains it very well :>

- https://solidity-by-example.org/constructor/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XwWBr4TAz4&t=1s
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/solidity/solidity_constructors.htm

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at the site you taught me.